# Data not updating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on a web app in Ionic. Here, I have a button in menu.html, which when clicked should cause a function in controllers.js to add newData to "data" in the appApi.js file but I am getting an error. Can someone take a look?
Here's the code in menu.html and controllers.html: http://pastebin.com/GW0h2G3P and here is appApi.js: http://pastebin.com/jbqqUbCP

Thanks!

Comment: addData is not present in your return object in appApi service. Add it to the return object

Answer (score 0):

In your `appapi` service

```
var addData = function(newData) {
    data[data.length] = newData;
}

return {
    getData: getData
};
```

`addData` is private. It's not exposed.

In your controller:
You are trying to access that addData which is not available.

```
 $scope.add = function() {
        appApi.addData($scope.newData);
    }
```

To fix it: add `addData` to your return object in service

var addData = function(newData) {
        data[data.length] = newData;
    }

```
return {
    getData: getData,
    addData  : addData
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you forgot to add adddata to your return object.

Your factory should look like this,

```
testApp.factory('appApi', function() {

    var data = [{
        "fName": "Starbucks",
        "id": 1,
    }];

    var getData = function() {
        return data;
    }

    var addData = function(newData) {
        data[data.length] = newData;
    }

    return {
        getData: getData,
          addData  : addData
    };

});
```

Here is the working [`Plnker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/pqWm0DTALFLSdlYOw3Js?p=preview)

Comment: did i miss anything in my answer that you've again mentioned same thing :)

Comment: I am a beginner and this is my first time working with Angular. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @mohamedrias Sorry i dint notice your answer when i posted, i was creating a plnker by that time. Absolutely no difference from your answer